# Survival plot appearance

Tags: r, plot, survival

I am trying to recreate the following plot -
[image: Cumulative incidence plot]
I found this plot in other papers so I thought maybe there is some package I have skipped.

I got a really close result using ggsurvplot function with [this tutorial -](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
but I failed to:

- Add the gap in the y axis
- Move tables titles "Number at risk"/"Cumulative number of events" above the two groups text.
- Add the two dots in the end of each table
- Change the font

Comment: There is [survminer R package](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survminer-r-package-survival-data-analysis-and-visualization)

Comment: I think so too. But I could not introduce the changes they did it.

Comment: Maybe you could share some data using `dput()`? So we can reproduce your desired plot.

Comment: You can use any survival data. data(veteran) from the survival package as an example. I really struggle with the gap in the y axis.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033743/how-can-i-insert-a-gap-into-y-axis-in-ggsurvplot